# How to send a file via MuleClient.send()

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

Is there a way to send a file via MuleClient.  Kind of like how VM's work where you can send mock-up messages?

```
MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
client.send("vm://testexception.in", payload, null);
```

Update per Learner's suggestion:

```
String inputFileName = "control_000001.dat";
String inputFileResourcePath = "TestFile/";
File inputFile = new File(Resources.getResource(inputFileResourcePath).toString(),inputFileName);
MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
client.dispatch("file:///tmp/muletest/input?connector=ConnectorName", inputFile, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send files also via `MuleClient`. You may want to use `dispatch` though instead of `send` as file endpoint is `one-way`.

```
muleClient.dispatch("file://D:/testDocs/in", inputFileName, null);
```

Comment: so "file://D:/test docs/in" is the directory and inputFileName is the full file name with extension?

Comment: No, `D:/test docs/in` is your `file:inbound-endpoint` and inputFileName  is your `File` object which has full file path and name

Comment: Is there documentation on how this file:inbound-endpoint name is defined? Still don't understand the construct of "D:/test docs/in".  Is "D:/test" the location of the xml config that defines the file:inbound-endpoint and "doc/in" is the name of the file:inbound-endpoint?

Comment: I've removed spaces between `test` and `Docs` to avoid confusion. `D:/testDocs/in` is the path in your xml config defining `file:inbound-endpoint`

Comment: Updated the question but still get an error with what I've done. Not sure what's the issue.